# How to update ubuntu repositories?

Tags: repository

I've just downloaded Bodhi Linux which is built on ubuntu 10.04 LTS. ubuntu 10.04 packages seems outdated and i cannot install newer versions of my packages. for example i need to install g++4.6 (to use some c++0x features) but i'm just able to install g++4.4. I added all backport repositories but they had no actual effect on version of packages. what should i do, can i add ubuntu natty's repositories to my software cources?

Answer (score 3):

From the Website for Bodhi Linux, their distribution, which was just released a few days ago, is based upon Ubuntu LTS. It would be technically challenging to add more recent Ubuntu packages and maintain coherence; that is why backports are limited.

Given that this distribution just had its initial release less than a week ago, it would probably be best to give the developers some time to backport more recent packages.

Alternately, if you really want the very latest, you may want to look at using other Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's ignore the fact that you aren't actually using Ubuntu, but some derived distribution. For simplicity, lets suppose you are using some version of Ubuntu, and want to backport packages from some later version. Personally, I would not use a custom distribution like this without a compelling reason. The level of support you will get is likely to be poor.

To address your example, it is very difficult to backport gcc in a binary Distribution like Ubuntu, so there usually aren't any such backports. At least, I've never come across them. Simply adding more recent versions of gcc, i.e. gcc 4.6 from a more recent version of Ubuntu to a release that doesn't have 4.6, is likely to cause problems. In fact, I posted [backporting more recent versions of the gcc toolchain to Debian stable](http://ask.debian.net/questions/backporting-more-recent-versions-of-the-gcc-toolchain-to-debian-stable) on exactly this topic. To sum up, you may want to consider a local install in this case. I have never done this, so have no idea of the difficulty involved.

It is not always so difficult to do backports of other packages. Often, it is perfectly feasible to do so oneself. Just because the backport does not exist does not mean it is difficult to do.

As far as using Ubuntu backports with Bodhi, this depends how compatible Bodhi is with Ubuntu. You may need to adapt the backports. Also, I suppose you are aware that the backports are generally available at lower priority so they don't install by default. You typically need to provide a `-t` flag to `apt-get` or similar for that to work. I'm not going into detauls because I don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

If you really want to use the most recent versions of packages, I recommend you use a source based distribution like Gentoo, which is designed to make it easier for different versions of packages to play together. Of course Gentoo etc. have their own problems with stability and QA. Also none of the source-based distributions have the kind of mindshare/backing that Ubuntu & Debian have.